# Power supply with 2 SEC outputs

Tags: power-supply

I have a bad power supply that needs to be replaced.  It shows the following:

```
PRI: 240V 50Hz 0.2A
SEC 1: 12V 1A DC
SEC 2: 4V AC 1A
Rating: 40VA
```

What is this type of power supply called? I am struggling to source a replacement.

Comment: Does [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this type of power supply called?

The general name is "dual output power supply" or "multiple output power supply".

If it's a part of another equipment then it's better to reach the manufacturer/distributor.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Will reach out to the manufacturer of the unit it powers up.